# Оптимизация Update

Tags: update, mysql

Есть необходимость обновлять базу, затрагивая 5-10 тыс записей. Если в цикле посылать по одному запросу то на это уходит примерно 80 сек (на 5 тыс записей). Если посылать кучу update в одном запросе, то уходит более 150 секунд на обработку.

Необходимо ускорить все это дело, в идеале до 2-5 секунд. 
Есть у кого какие идеи на этот счет?

PS

бд. mysql

яп php

пример запроса

```
update product set price=7  where sku = '123';
```

UPD По своей глупости, позабыл про индексы. Добавил индекс на sku время уменьшилось до 1 секунды с копейками.

Но все же, может есть еще какие то варианты ускорить данное действие?

Comment: Delete + Insert?

Comment: если запросов много - заверните в транзакцию.

Comment: на вскидку

    create temporary table t (...);
    insert into t(id, fld) values (..),(..)...;
    update tab
      join t on tab.sku = t.id
      set tab.price = fld;

не проверял.

Answer (score 1):

Какой тип таблицы? Желательно для такого дела сделать **innoDB**.

Расскажите более подробно о спецификации задачи. По какому признаку Вы обновляете данные? Если возможно объединить строки по какому-то признаку, то это следует зделать и использовать в `WHERE` Вашего запроса.